# Why does my array start with empty value?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I can't wrap my head around this one.

When I create an array it begins with an empty value. The values that needs to be in the array starts as second.

Array:

```
Array ( 

 [0] => 

 [1] => Value 1 

 [2] => Value 2 

 [3] => Value 3

)
```

Code:

```
$categories = array();
$query2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM books_categories");
do{
    array_push($categories, $category['description']);
}while($category=mysql_fetch_assoc($query2));
```

How do I accomplish to get the first item in the array to be Value 1?

Comment: I think you should turn on error reporting and see what's up.

Comment: @AlvinWong - there won't be any errors here; this is a logic problem, not a syntax or query problem.

Comment: @MrSlippyFist - in case you're wondering why half the answers are telling you to stop using the `mysql_xx()` functions, it's because they're deprecated and not recommended for use. See [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php) for more info and what to do about it.

Comment: @SDC OK you win. That'll be a NOTICE, not error.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It is because of do while loop try while loop

```
while($category=mysql_fetch_assoc($query2)){
    array_push($categories, $category['description']);
}
```

Comment: You're the fastest one and too fast.

Comment: Though it is recommended to do this: `while(($category = mysql_fetch_assoc($query2)) !== false)`. This will make sure it doesn't crash when there is an error in the query or if there are no rows.

Comment: @Rune your `!== false` bit isn't necessary; if it equals false, it will drop out of the loop just fine with the code in the answer because `$category` will be set to false, which will terminate the `while` loop.

Comment: @SDC That depends on your config. On my webhost, when there are no rows and I don't use the `!== false`, it errors.

Comment: @Rune - please elaborate. I stand by my previous comment that the while loop should drop out without it, but I'd be interested to know what config you have that would cause that behaviour, and what the error is that it generates.

Comment: @SDC Hmm, my host just updated last night and I don't get an error anymore if I try it.. Been a while since I've seen the error, since I always use `false`. It probably was a bug from my host that got solved, so ignore my comments. Even so, it will help to remove the annoying `assignment in condition` warnings in your editor (Zend Studio does that for example).

Answer (score 14):

The answer is very simple: you are pushing the first element before you read the first row. The right way of doing it would be with a pre-condition loop:

```
$categories = array();
$query2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM books_categories");

while($category=mysql_fetch_assoc($query2)) {
    array_push($categories, $category['description']);
}
```

And, please switch to using PDO.

Answer (score 12):

How do while loop works

> [image]
>
> The main difference from regular while loops is that the first iteration of a do-while loop is guaranteed to run (the truth expression is only checked at the end of the iteration), whereas it may not necessarily run with a regular while loop (the truth expression is checked at the beginning of each iteration, if it evaluates to FALSE right from the beginning, the loop execution would end immediately).[source](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.do.while.php)

so in your program what happened  you are pushing the first element before you read the first row.

so use while instead

what wile loop will do ? as in flow chart it will check first than come inside loop body so element is push after read the first row

```
$categories = array();
$query2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM books_categories");

while($category=mysql_fetch_assoc($query2)) {
    array_push($categories, $category['description']);
}
```

---

**Note**

1. The entire **`ext/mysql`** PHP extension, which provides all functions named with the prefix mysql_, is [officially deprecated as of PHP v5.5.0](http://php.net/manual/en/changelog.mysql.php) and will be removed in the future. So use either `PDO` or `MySQLi`

**Good read**

1. [The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944956/the-mysql-extension-is-deprecated-and-will-be-removed-in-the-future-use-mysqli/13944958#comment19236631_13944958)

Comment: Best answer. It's got a flowchart, a textual explanation, it mentions the deprecation of the API... what else do you need?

Answer (score 5):

Because you should use a while loop instead of the do-while loop.

```
while($category = mysql_fetch_assoc($query2)) {
    array_push($categories, $category['description']);
}
```

In your code instead in the first iteration of the loop (when entering the do block for the first time), `$category` is not set therefore setting the first array value to be empty.

Answer (score 5):

You first write the value (`array_push()`) into the array and then you actually grab the value (`mysql_fetch_assoc()`).

You need to *first* grab the value and *then* place it into your array!

```
$categories = array();
$query2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM books_categories");
while(($category = mysql_fetch_assoc($query2)) !=== false) {
    array_push($categories, $category['description']);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this instead:

```
$categories = array();
$query2 = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM books_categories');
while($r = mysql_fetch_array($query2)){
    $categories[] = $r['description'];
}
```

Comment: @mauris - Someone here does not like spaces i see :-)

Comment: while I removed 3 spaces, I added 4 other spaces for indentation. Since -3 + 4 = 1, you can say that I still like spaces.

Comment: @maurius I approve your equation and accept your answer. You may now fly away :D